# Multi line labels in c3 charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, multiline, label, c3.js

How to implement multiline labels in c3 charts?

Please refer - http://c3js.org/samples/axes_label.html

In the above example, you can see the "x label" label is showing as

x label

But I want it be broken down in two words, and finally display as

x
label

This is SVG, and not normal html. How to do it?

Comment: Not a single comment? single answer? oh common...

Comment: what do you mean broken down into two words? x label is already 2 words.

Answer (score 1):

I have broken it into two DOM elements of `tspan` like this

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['sample', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['sample2', 130, 300, 200, 500, 250, 350]
        ],
        axes: {
            sample2: 'y2'
        }
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            label: 'x-label'
        },
        y: {
            label: 'Y Label'
        },
        y2: {
            show: true,
            label: 'Y2 Label'
        }
    }
});
var label = d3.select(".c3-axis-x-label");
var text = label.text();//this will give you the text
label.text("");//setting the label to be blank

label.append("tspan").text("hello ");//making a tspan and adding to x label DOM
label.append("tspan").text("World");//making a tspan and adding to x label text DOM
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/4Lkq7w8x/)

**EDIT**

You can place the label by adjusting the dx and dy attribute

```
label.append("tspan").text("hello ").attr("dx", -30);;//making a tspan and adding to x label DOM
label.append("tspan").text("World").attr("dy", 20).attr("dx", -25);//making a tspan and adding to x label text DOM
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/4Lkq7w8x/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello and world are in the same line. I require both of them in 2 separate lines.

Comment: You can then style it with CSS I guess